# Macro __TIMESTAMP__ gets stuck

Tags: c++, timestamp

Hi,

I'm currently working on a project that has it's own logging system, written years ago, and it uses `__TIMESTAMP__` to print the current date and time. What I've noticed is that sometimes, this macro gets stuck, and keeps returning the same value over and over again. For example it was 12:37 and the macro kept returning 11:16, the time of the previous run.

Does `__TIMESTAMP__` have a portion of memory that needs dealocation before every call? Since it's used for years and no one else noticed, can it be a problem from my computer?

Comment: Could we see some code?

Comment: Afaik ```__TIMESTAMP__``` does not print the current time, but the time the executable was compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @SebastianPhilipp's comment, `__TIMESTAMP__` represents the time at which the executable was compiled. As an alternative, I would recommend looking at functions such as `ctime()` and `asctime()`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot print current date and time with `__TIMESTAMP__` because it is preprocessor pragma. It will always show project compile time, not current time. Use [time(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) to get current time.

Answer (score 1):

**TIMESTAMP** is a preprocessor macro that expands to current time (at compile time) in the form Ddd Mmm Date hh::mm::ss yyyy， you can get more infomation [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__TIMESTAMP__.html)

Here is an sample for log

```
static char* time_to_string(time_t t, char* buf, size_t bufsize) 
{
            struct tm tm;
            strftime(buf, bufsize, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime_r(&t, &tm));
            return buf;
}

extern "C" void log_printf(FILE* stream, const char* format, ...)
{
        char t[32];

        flockfile(stream);

        fprintf(stream, "[%s] ", time_to_string(time(NULL), t, sizeof(t)));

        va_list va;
        va_start(va, format);
        vfprintf(stream, format, va);
        va_end(va);

        funlockfile(stream);
}
```